# How to overwrite the nosetest teardown function?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

When testing with `nosetest` the result of each test case can be 'success', 'failure' or an 'error'. This is being written to STDOUT as '.', 'F' and 'E'.

- .
- F
- E

Is there a way to overwrite this function and to print out additional debugging information?

**Addendum**

Based on the information given below I have created the following test code:

```
from nose.tools import assert_true
from nose.plugins import Plugin

class Tester(Plugin):

    def addSuccess(self, test):
        print("Test successful")

    def addError(self, test, err):
        print("Had error: %s" % err)

    def addFailure(self, test, err):
        print("Had failure: %s" % err)


class TestSuite(object):
    def test1(self):
        assert_true(True)
```

However, no additional output is generated when I run this example test with

```
nosetests --nologcapture -s test1.py
```

Do I need to 'register' that plugin somehow?

**Addendum2:**

I have created a file `plugin1.py` with the following content:

```
import os
from nose.plugins import Plugin

class Plugin1(Plugin):
    def addSuccess(self, test):
        print("Test successful")

    def addError(self, test, err):
        print("Had error: %s" % err)

    def addFailure(self, test, err):
        print("Had failure: %s" % err)

    def options(self, parser, env=os.environ):
        super(Plugin1, self).options(parser, env=env)

    def configure(self, options, conf):
        super(Plugin1, self).configure(options, conf)
```

and the test script as follows (`test1.py`):

```
from nose.tools import assert_true


class TestSuite(object):
    def test1(self):
        assert_true(True)


import nose
from plugin1 import Plugin1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nose.main(addplugins=[Plugin1()])
```

But I get still the same result. I guess I have to 'register' the plugin somehow else. But how? The [documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/writing.html) on this point is virtually non-existent...

Running the whole test by

```
python test1.py
```

yields the same output, but not the additional textual output given in `plugin1.py`.

Comment: what extra information are you looking for? For the failed test nose will display the stack trace as well

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the `nose` [plug-in framework](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/writing.html). Basically your plug-in needs to provide an `addError` method, which gets called when a test errors. The method gets the test case passed in, and you should be able to introspect what went wrong and log extra debugging information there. Have a look at the [TestTextResult](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/result.html) and [ResultProxy](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/proxy.html) classes.

The examples contain a complete plug-in that modifies the output stream ([HTMLPlugin](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/examples/html_plugin/htmlplug.py)) to be html formatted.

---

**update**

The documentation is indeed very bad. Here's what I've pieced together.

```
import sys
from nose.tools import assert_true
import nose
from nose.plugins import Plugin

class Plugin1(Plugin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reports = []
        # self.name = 'mega-plugin'
        super(Plugin1, self).__init__()

    def addSuccess(self, test):
        print('Test successful')
        self.reports.append("Test successful")
        self.stream.writeln("Test successful")

    def setOutputStream(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream
        return None

    def finalize(self, result):
        for t in self.reports:
            self.stream.writeln('finalize - ' + t)

class TestSuite(object):
    def test1(self):
        assert_true(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nose.main(argv=sys.argv + ['--with-plugin1'], addplugins=[Plugin1()])
```

the output from that is

```
Test successful
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

OK
finalize - Test successful
```

A couple of observations:

1. using `addplugins` only *registers* the plugin it doesn't enable it
2. you have to specify `--with-PLUGIN-NAME` to actually use it
3. the `--with-PLUGIN-NAME` can not be first in `argv` as that would traditionally be the program name
4. plug ins get an automatic name from the class name and an automatic `--with-PLUGIN-NAME` flag, you can override the name and thus also the `--with-SOMETHING` flag.
5. if you want to print to `stderr` while the tests are running you have to also specify `--nocapture` otherwise `nose` will block stdout (notice that the `print` from `addSuccess` is not shown in the output)
6. you should implement a `setOutputStream` method and store a local reference to the output stream, or have your own output stream set up possibly during `__init__`.
7. if you have a `setOutputStream` method *and* return None from it, the other plugins can use that same stream. You can return a dummy stream to suppress the default output (https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/writing.html#recipes)
8. to keep everything nice and tidy, you should also implement a `finalize` method and only print the output there, not while the tests are running - `addSucces`, `addFailure` etc. are called during the test, `finalize` is called once all tests have completed.

All of this really should be in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, but how to get it work? I created a Plugins class in the test script, but the output did not change. How to use such a plugin?

Comment: You can use `argv=sys.argv + ['--with-plugin1']`, so that it's still possible to pass command line arguments on the command line

Comment: @MattiLyra: Thanks for the explicit example, but it does not work for me. I tried to run the script with `nosetest -s test1.py` and `nosetests test1.py` as well as `python test1.py`. I still get the original unchanged output.

Comment: It looks like the 'main' part is not executed at all (when using `nosetests`)

Comment: I run it as `python test1.py` and it does work. I'm on `nose-1.3.7` and `python-3.5.2` - calling `nosetest` won't work as that'll skip the `.main` runner as you already discovered. Can you turn on `--nocapture` and insert some `print` statements to see if anything gets called?

Comment: I am still using python 2.7 currently. Maybe that is affecting the issue?

Comment: @Alex try ... nose.main(defaultTest=sys.argv[0], argv=['--with-plugin1'], addplugins=[Plugin1()])  ... it should work